# ASP.NET Core MVC & ASP.NET Core Web API in same project

Tags: asp.net-core

[enter image description here][1]I want to build ASP.NET Core MVC & ASP.NET Core Web API in the same project. There are various solutions to this problem but they are for older versions of the framework.

How is this done for ASP.NET Core 7?

I try this but it's not work
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq2wQ.png

Comment: What exactly you have tried and what exactly does not work for you?

Comment: Do you want to add mvc controller and api controller in the same project ?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how to config

Comment: There is nothing to config. You just create the MVC project and add API controllers to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a MVC project, and then add api controller like picture:
[image]

Then you can use url like:https://localhost:7182/api/values
Read  [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more.